# Вывод переменных из подпроцесса в родительский процесс в Python

Tags: python-3.x

У меня такой вопрос. Есть подпроцесс который считает какое то простое число. Как мне по завершению процесса передать это число в родительский процесс, что бы провести там с ним дальнейшие манипуляции. Под процесс вызываю так:
`process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "fileName.py", str(account[0])])`

Вроде как, необходимо использовать параметр stdout, но как его использовать не могу разобраться.

`process1 = subprocess.Popen(arg, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1)`

Если использовать такую конструкцию то все что я печатаю в консоль в process1, в консоль не выводится а переправляется в родительский процесс.

Всем спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
with subprocess.Popen(["ls"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    print("<<<"+proc.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")+">>>")
```

Comment: Наверное не точно задал вопрос. Мне необходимо что бы и в подпроцессе в консоль выводилось что то и по завершении процесса он передавал какие то данные в родительский процесс. А так получается что все print копятся в родительском процессе и потом кучей печатаются

Comment: Если в консоль одно, а родителю другое, то
можно в файл писать, или именованый канал. Путь к файлу передать через аргумент.

Comment: Можно конечно наоткрывать дескрипторов, сделать форк и т. д., но оно того, наверно, не стоит.

Comment: В файл думал... Но вроде как то громоздко получается ради пары чисел. А что за именованный канал?

Comment: 1) В принципе ребенок может писать в stderr в процессе выполнения, а результат в stdout .
2) Wikipedia может рссказать про Именованный_канал и Неименованный_канал. Для пары чисел именованный, вроде смысла нет.
3) С неименованным можно как-то так: `os.pipe ... os.fork` (и по желанию `os.exec*`) 4) Если в файл, то есть `tempfile` 5) можно вообще веб-сервер сделать, и слать ему запросы